# Detect inline elements with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, cheerio

Is it possible to detect inline elements with cheerio? For example:

```
<div>
  Hello
  <strong>there</strong>
  John!
</div>
```

This is an example of an inline element I would like to detect, because to a reader, the `strong` tag is very clearly a continuation of the rest of the phrase. However, compared to something like this:

```
<div>
  Jobs
  <span>Cleaner</span>
  <span>Artist</span>
</div>
```

These aren't exactly inline, because to a reader, they are clearly separated.

I guess what I'm asking is, is it possible to use cheerio to detect if an element is sandwiched between the text of its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The term `inline elements` might not be the best to describe what you are trying to achieve.

The basic steps I would take are:

- use [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childnodes) to get a nodelist of child text *and*
  html elements.
- Then use [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) or similar to figure out if the node is an
  element or text.
- Then check if the text elements have more than just white space characters in their respective `textContent` or data.

Working with js, one way this could be accomplished is like so:

```js
function markSandwichedEls(parent) {
  var children = parent.childNodes;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (
      children[i].nodeType === 1 &&
      children[i - 1].nodeType === 3 &&
      children[i - 1].textContent.replace(/\s/g, "").length &&
      children[i + 1].nodeType === 3 &&
      children[i + 1].textContent.replace(/\s/g, "").length
    ) {
      children[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
  markSandwichedEls(div);
});
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <strong>there</strong> John!
</div>

<div>
  Jobs
  <span>Cleaner</span>
  <span>Artist</span>
</div>
```

So by applying a very similar approach, this could be achieved in cheerio like so:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const $ = cheerio.load(`
<div>
  Hello
  <strong>there</strong> John!
</div>

<div>
  Jobs
  <span>Cleaner</span>
  <span>Artist</span>
</div>
`)

const divs = $('div')
divs.toArray().forEach(div => {
  div.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if (
      child.type === 'tag' && 
      child.prev.type === 'text' &&
      child.prev.data.trim() !== '' && 
      child.next.type === 'text' &&
      child.next.data.trim() !== ''
      ) {
      console.log(child)
    }
  })
})
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bbxe9x)